# Resistive load (voltage and current monitoring)

Tags: pwm, current-measurement, voltage-measurement

I would like to design a circuit to drive a resistive load (around 3 to 4 ohms) with a maximum current of 2 amps. I want to monitor both voltage and current delivered to the resistive load.

I have designed a first version of the circuit with PWM (20kHz) and a Mosfet. I use a voltage divider to monitor the voltage and an INA169 for the current.

[image]

However, voltage and current measurements contain the PWM signal. I tried to filter the outputs, but the result is not very accurate.

Does someone have a better solution to do the monitoring ? Is it possible not to use PWM without dissipating too much energy ?

Comment: If the PWM is from a microcontroller, and your load can tolerate small bursts of full power, you can implement pulse stretching: Periodically set the duty cycle to 100%, quickly do your measurements, then set the duty cycle back to whatever it's supposed to be.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I would have to synchronise PWM with analog reading of the microcontroller. It don't feel confortable implementing this solution.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is the basics of a buck converter so, by adding a capacitor, an inductor and a fly-back diode you can significantly reduce the size of the pulses delivered to your load down to a few milli volts peak to peak: -

[image]

Choose L and C so that resonance occurs at a low frequency compared to your switching frequency (maybe 100 Hz).